# Is it possible to use openssl to decrypt files to memory instead of to disk file

Tags: php, encryption, openssl

I can successfully encrypt and decrypt files using openssl. However, the only reference I can find is that the output is to a file

Instead of having to write to disk, I need to decrypt audio files into memory and then be able to play the audio.
currently I use the following:

```
  try {
      exec("openssl smime -decrypt -inform DER -in ".$filetoplay." -out " . $outfilename . " -inkey " . $rsakey);
      if (file_exists($outfilename)) {
          $returnedValue = file_get_contents($outfilename);
          unlink($outfilename);
          echo $returnedValue;
      }
  } catch (exception $e) {
      echo "\n did not decrypt with " . $certname;
  }
```

I do a quick decrypt to a file, then get the contents with file_get_contents($outputfilename), then I delete the unencrypted file from disk.
This causes a security issue where I don't want there to be any unencrypted copy of the file anywhere.

Is there a way to replace the $outputfilename with a blob object ? or direct the $outputfilename to memory ?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It might be easier if you tried [decrypting it using PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-decrypt.php)?

Comment: needs to be smime type and even php's option appears to need a filename. 
 --    openssl_pkcs7_decrypt ( string $input_filename , string $output_filename , OpenSSLCertificate|string $certificate , OpenSSLAsymmetricKey|OpenSSLCertificate|array|string|null $private_key = null ) : bool